# How to unblock/drain a grpc::CompletionQueue waiting on a state change?

Tags: c++, grpc, grpc-c++

In the following MCVE, I have a thread waiting on a grpc::CompletionQueue that is waiting on a state change:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace grpc;

void threadFunc(shared_ptr<Channel> ch, CompletionQueue* cq) {
  void* tag = NULL;
  bool ok = false;
  int i = 1;
  grpc_connectivity_state state = ch->GetState(false);

  cout << "state " << i++ << " = " << (int)state << endl;
  ch->NotifyOnStateChange(state,
                          gpr_inf_future(GPR_CLOCK_MONOTONIC),
                          cq,
                          (void*)1);

  while (cq->Next(&tag, &ok)) {
    state = ch->GetState(false);
    cout << "state " << i++ << " = " << (int)state << endl;
    ch->NotifyOnStateChange(state,
                            gpr_inf_future(GPR_CLOCK_MONOTONIC),
                            cq,
                            (void*)1);
  }

  cout << "thread end" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  ChannelArguments channel_args;
  CompletionQueue cq;

  channel_args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_MAX_PINGS_WITHOUT_DATA, 0);
  channel_args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_MIN_RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS, 2000);
  channel_args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_MAX_RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS, 2000);
  channel_args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_BDP_PROBE, 0);
  channel_args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_TIME_MS, 60000);
  channel_args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT_MS, 30000);
  channel_args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_MIN_SENT_PING_INTERVAL_WITHOUT_DATA_MS,
                      60000);

  {
    shared_ptr<Channel> ch(CreateCustomChannel("my_grpc_server:50051",
                                               InsecureChannelCredentials(),
                                               channel_args));
    std::thread my_thread(&threadFunc, ch, &cq);
    cout << "sleeping" << endl;
    sleep(5);
    cout << "slept" << endl;
    cq.Shutdown();
    cout << "shut down cq" << endl;
    my_thread.join();
  }
}
```

Output of the running executable:

```
$ ./a.out
sleeping
state 1 = 0
slept
shut down cq
```

The observed behavior is that the executable hangs joining `my_thread`.
This is because `CompletionQueue::Next()` does not unblock.
I am aware that it is necessary to call `CompletionQueue::Shutdown()` to make `CompletionQueue::Next()` unblock and return `false`.
Since that is already done in the code above, what else is missing? **Why does `CompletionQueue::Next()` not unblock and return false even though `CompletionQueue::Shutdown()` has been called?**

Answer (score 1):

`Shutdown()` causes `Next()` to awaken once for each of the pending operations with `ok == false` and return value `true`. Only after that, after the queue is drained, will `Next()` return `false`.

After calling `Shutdown()`, one is not permitted to queue new work on the `CompletionQueue`. The call to `NotifyOnStateChange()` inside the loop is doing precisely that.

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure about that first statement in your answer. If `Shutdown()` caused `Next()` to awaken once, then "`state 2 = ...`" should have been printed to stdout, because the code is definitely executing `Shutdown()`. Rather, the observed behavior implies that `Shutdown()` is _not_ causing the `Next()` to awaken. My hypothesis is that this is because 1) the "action" added to the queue has an infinite timeout and 2) there is no change in channel-state, to trigger "completion" of the "action." That's just my hypothesis, and I'm struggling to get an answer to that.

Comment: I think I understand your point about not being permitted to queue new work on the `CompletionQueue` after calling `Shutdown()`...but I don't think that problem is being exercised yet in the code as posted...I think the problem being demonstrated is the seeming failure of `Shutdown()` to awaken the `CompletionQueue` in the first place.

Comment: Ok... I can confirm this is not the issue causing the immediate behavior. I can update the answer perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `CompletionQueue::Shutdown()`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_completion_queue.html#a40efddadd9073386fbcb4f46e8325670) says:

> Next will not return false until this method has been called and all pending tags have been drained.

In other words, the CQ will not shut down until the already-pending tag that you requested via `NotifyOnStateChange()` is completed.

However, the way you've currently written this code, `NotifyOnStateChange()` will *never* complete, even if you don't do any shutdown.  This is because you're asking it to tell you when the channel's state has changed, but you're not triggering any operation that would ever cause the channel's state to change, so that will never happen.  I believe that if you remove the shutdown and just let this program run forever, you will never see the state change occur.

If you change the code to do something to trigger the channel to start connecting (either by sending an RPC on the channel, or by changing the argument of the first `GetState()` call from `false` to `true`), then you will see the connectivity state change, and then the CQ will shut down after that state change is delivered.

I hope this is helpful.